# FFmpeg: generating H264 video in c++

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

Im using ffmpeg library in windows with vs2012 to convert a series of images into Mp4 with H264 encoding. Im new to FFMPEG.

Below is my code. Everything went fine. Video is created.But i can play the video in vlc player only if i changed the extension to ".h264", also when i check for codec information it says "H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)". but when i checked the same for other mp4 videos which are downloaded from web. it says "H264 - MPEG-4" AVC (part 10) (avc1)". I dont understand where it went wrong. Also i searched a lot, some says like add SPS and PPS.

```
const uint8_t sps[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00,
0x0a, 0xf8, 0x41, 0xa2 };
const uint8_t pps[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xce,
0x38, 0x80 };
```

So i added the above value to video file before i add the image stream. But no luck.
 Can anyone help on this..Thanks in advance.

```
const uint8_t sps[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00,
0x0a, 0xf8, 0x41, 0xa2 };
const uint8_t pps[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xce,
0x38, 0x80 };
const uint8_t slice_header[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05, 0x88,
0x84, 0x21, 0xa0 };
const uint8_t macroblock_header[] = { 0x0d, 0x00 };

const uint8_t spspps[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00, 0x0a, 0xf8, 0x41, 0xa2, 
                           0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xce, 0x38, 0x80
                         };

int ff_load_image(uint8_t *data[4], int linesize[4],
        int *w, int *h, enum PixelFormat *pix_fmt,
        const char *filename, void *log_ctx)
    {
        AVInputFormat *iformat = NULL;
        AVFormatContext *format_ctx = NULL;
        AVCodec *codec=NULL;
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx=NULL;
        AVFrame *frame=NULL;
        int frame_decoded, ret = 0;
        AVPacket pkt;

        av_register_all();

        iformat = av_find_input_format("image2");
        if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, filename, iformat, NULL)) < 0) {
            return ret;
        }

        codec_ctx = format_ctx->streams[0]->codec;
        codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_ctx->codec_id);
        if (!codec) {
            ret = AVERROR(EINVAL);
            goto end;
        }

        if ((ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, NULL)) < 0) {
            goto end;
        }

        //if (!(frame = avcodec_alloc_frame()) ) {
        if (!(frame = av_frame_alloc()) ) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_read_frame(format_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(codec_ctx, frame, &frame_decoded, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0 || !frame_decoded) {
            goto end;
        }
        ret = 0;

        *w       = frame->width;
        *h       = frame->height;
        *pix_fmt = (PixelFormat)frame->format;

        if ((ret = av_image_alloc(data, linesize, *w, *h, (AVPixelFormat)*pix_fmt, 16)) < 0)
            goto end;
        ret = 0;

        av_image_copy(data, linesize, (const uint8_t **)frame->data, frame->linesize, (AVPixelFormat)*pix_fmt, *w, *h);

end:
        if(codec_ctx) { avcodec_close(codec_ctx); }
        if(format_ctx) { avformat_close_input(&format_ctx); }
        if(frame) { av_freep(&frame); }
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
                return ret;
    }

    int load_image_into_frame(AVFrame *frame, const char *filename)
    {
        int retval = -1, res;
        static struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
        uint8_t *image_data[4];
        int linesize[4];
        int source_width, source_height;
        enum PixelFormat source_fmt;

        res = ff_load_image(image_data, linesize, &source_width, &source_height, &source_fmt, filename, NULL);

        if (source_fmt != frame->format) {
            sws_ctx = sws_getContext(source_width, source_height, (AVPixelFormat)source_fmt,
                frame->width, frame->height, (AVPixelFormat)frame->format,
                sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            sws_scale(sws_ctx,
                (const uint8_t * const *)image_data, linesize,
                0, frame->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
        }

        retval = 0;
error:
        av_freep(&image_data[0]);
        sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
        return retval;
    }

    int write_frame_to_file(FILE *file, AVFrame *frame, AVCodecContext *codec_context, AVPacket *pkt) {
        int res, got_output;
        av_init_packet(pkt);
        pkt->data = NULL;
        pkt->size = 0;

        /* generate synthetic video */
        frame->pts += 30;

        res = avcodec_encode_video2(codec_context, pkt, frame, &got_output);

        if (got_output) {

            fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, file);
            av_free_packet(pkt);
        }
        return 0;
error:
        return -1;
    }

    int write_image_to_file(FILE *file, const char *filename, int count, AVFrame *frame, AVCodecContext *codec_context, AVPacket *pkt) {
        int res, i;
        res = load_image_into_frame(frame, filename);

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            res = write_frame_to_file(file, frame, codec_context, pkt);
        }

        return 0;
error:
        return -1;
    }

    int write_delayed_frames_to_file(FILE *file, AVFrame *frame, AVCodecContext *codec_context, AVPacket *pkt) {
        int res, got_output;

        for (got_output = 1; got_output;) {
            res = avcodec_encode_video2(codec_context, pkt, NULL, &got_output);

            if (got_output) {
                fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, file);
                av_free_packet(pkt);
            }
        }

        return 0;
error:
        return -1;
    }

    AVCodecContext *get_codec_context(int width, int height, int fps)
    {
        int res;
        avcodec_register_all();

        AVCodec *codec;
        AVCodecContext *codec_context = NULL;

        codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

        codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

        codec_context->bit_rate = 441000;
        codec_context->width = width;
        codec_context->height = height;
        AVRational temp_113 = {1, fps};
        AVRational temp_114 = {fps, 1};
        codec_context->time_base= temp_113;
        codec_context->gop_size = 10;
        codec_context->max_b_frames=1;
        codec_context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;        

        res = avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, NULL);

        return codec_context;
error:
        return NULL;
    }

    AVFrame *get_av_frame(AVCodecContext *codec_context) {
        int res;
        AVFrame *frame;

        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        frame->height = codec_context->height;
        frame->width = codec_context->width;
        frame->format = codec_context->pix_fmt;
        frame->pts = 0;

        res = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, frame->width, frame->height, (AVPixelFormat)frame->format, 1);

        return frame;
error:
        return NULL;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        const char *filename = "result video\\test.mp4";
        FILE *file=NULL;
        int res, retval=-1;
        AVCodecContext *codec_context= NULL;
        AVFrame *frame=NULL;
        AVPacket pkt;
        uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

        codec_context = get_codec_context(1920, 1080, 30);

        file = fopen(filename, "wb");
        //check(file != NULL, "could not open destination file %s", filename);

        frame = get_av_frame(codec_context);        

        //fwrite(sps, 1, sizeof(sps), file);
        //fwrite(pps, 1, sizeof(pps), file);

        /*codec_context->extradata = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * sizeof(spspps));

        for(unsigned int index = 0; index < sizeof(spspps); index++)
        {
            codec_context->extradata[index] = spspps[index];
        }

        codec_context->extradata_size = (int)sizeof(spspps);*/

        codec_context->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

        int i, frames= 51;
        for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss<<"\\frames\\out"<<( i + 1)<<".jpg";
            res = write_image_to_file(file, ss.str().c_str(), 3, frame, codec_context, &pkt);
        }


        res = write_delayed_frames_to_file(file, frame, codec_context, &pkt);
        fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), file);

        retval = 0;
error:
        if (file)
            fclose(file);
        if (codec_context) {
            avcodec_close(codec_context);
            av_free(codec_context);
        }
        if (frame) {
            av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
            av_free(frame);
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using an `AVFormatContext` for your encoding, so I see a reason you're not able to output an .mp4 file as desired.

You should:

1. Use an AVFormatContext
2. Set an [AVOutputFormat](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/structAVOutputFormat.html) to AVFormatContext->[oformat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/structAVFormatContext.html#a20d80ac07e38ff5c268d15aaf2798b98) (Output Format) either directly or using a function like [avformat_alloc_output_context2()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/avformat_8h.html#a6ddf3d982feb45fa5081420ee911f5d5)
3. Optional: set flags if necessary and call [avio_open2()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/avio_8h.html#ade8a63980569494c99593ebf0d1e891b) to access the resource.
4. Call [avformat_write_header()](http://avformat_write_header)

I would post code but there are many examples online which you can find using mixing these function names with "ffmpeg encoding" keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:-). your tips are so useful. i got some examples like you said, but they dont let me to write the pixel data to file. i was supposed to call the function "av_interleaved_write_frame()". this function internally writing AVPacket to output file. but my requirement is getting the video buffer, it should not be written directly to file.